# FastReport does not see my DataTable

Tags: c#, datatable, fastreport

I have a datatable and i want to bind it to fastreport Table Object, but it does not work. I use C#  and visual studio 2015. My frx file matches to my datatable. My Table Object name matches with my register data parameters. But still it does not work. Please Help, thanks all. 
Here is my C# source

```
using (Report report = new Report())
        {

            report.Load(@"C:\Users\sevket\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\OnMuhasebe\OnMuhasebe\bin\Debug\isimsiz.frx"); //Loading frx

            DataTable tablo = new DataTable(); //starts my data table
            DataColumn sutun; //my columns
            sutun = new DataColumn("kod"); //0
            tablo.Columns.Add(sutun);
            sutun = new DataColumn("cinsi"); //1
            tablo.Columns.Add(sutun);
            sutun = new DataColumn("miktar"); //2
            tablo.Columns.Add(sutun);
            sutun = new DataColumn("birimfiyat"); //3
            tablo.Columns.Add(sutun);
            sutun = new DataColumn("tutar"); //4
            tablo.Columns.Add(sutun);

            for (int i = 0; i < dgvFaturaListe.Rows.Count - 1; i++)//my datarows
            {
                DataRow satir;
                satir = tablo.NewRow();
                satir["kod"] = dgvFaturaListe.Rows[i + 1].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
                satir["cinsi"] = dgvFaturaListe.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
                satir["miktar"] = dgvFaturaListe.Rows[i + 1].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
                satir["birimfiyat"] = dgvFaturaListe.Rows[i + 1].Cells[6].Value.ToString();
                satir["tutar"] = dgvFaturaListe.Rows[i + 1].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
                tablo.Rows.Add(satir);
                i++;
            }


            report.RegisterData(tablo, "Tablo");// passing table to frx





            if (report.Prepare())
            {
                // Hazırlanmış olan raporun gösterilmesini sağlıyoruz.
                report.ShowPrepared();
            }

        }
```

And here is my frx tableObject

```
<TableObject Name="Tablo" Left="94.5" Top="378" Width="708.75" Height="37.8">
    <TableColumn Name="kod" Width="94.5"/>
    <TableColumn Name="cinsi" Width="302.4"/>
    <TableColumn Name="miktar" Width="94.5"/>
    <TableColumn Name="birimfiyat" Width="94.5"/>
    <TableColumn Name="tutar" Width="122.85"/>
    <TableRow Name="Row1">
      <TableCell Name="Cell1"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell2"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell3"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell4"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell5"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow Name="Row2">
      <TableCell Name="Cell6"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell7"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell8"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell9"/>
      <TableCell Name="Cell10"/>
    </TableRow>
  </TableObject>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this question?